# gcc bitwise odd behavior

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation

I'm getting back to C after a long absence and I'm trying to learn the bitwise operators. I wrote this little program to demonstrate my confusion. The first printf works (after the header), but not the second. Is this some kind of order of operations thing or what?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    b[0] = '\0';

    int z;
    for (z = 128; z > 0; z >>= 1)
        {
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
        }

    return b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int ch = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int a = atoi(argv[2]);
    int chA;
    int chB;
    int chC;
    int chD;
    int chE;
    int chF;
    chA = ch & a;
    chB = ch | a;
    chC = ch ^ a;
    chD = ~ch;
    chE = ch << 2;
    chF = ch >> 2;
    char chAS[16];
    char chBS[16];
    char chCS[16];
    char chDS[16];
    char chES[16];
    char chFS[16];
    strcpy(chAS, byte_to_binary(chA));
    strcpy(chBS, byte_to_binary(chB));
    strcpy(chCS, byte_to_binary(chC));
    strcpy(chDS, byte_to_binary(chD));
    strcpy(chES, byte_to_binary(chE));
    strcpy(chFS, byte_to_binary(chF));

    printf("[c][%%d ][%%o ][%%x][   %%s  ][   &    ][   |    ][   ^    ][   ~    ][  <<    ][   >>   ]\n");
    printf("[%c][%03d][%03o][%02x][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s]\n", isprint(ch) ? ch : ' ', ch, ch, ch, byte_to_binary(ch), chAS, chBS, chCS, chDS, chES, chFS);
    printf("[%c][%03d][%03o][%02x][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s][%s]\n", isprint(ch) ? ch : ' ', ch, ch, ch, byte_to_binary(ch), byte_to_binary(ch & a), byte_to_binary(ch | a), byte_to_binary(ch ^ a), byte_to_binary(~ch), byte_to_binary(ch << 2), byte_to_binary(ch >> 2));

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `byte_to_binary` function returns a pointer to a static array.  You then call `printf`, passing the return value of this function multiple times, and each of those calls returns the **same** pointer, so whichever invocation of the function happens to come last will be the one the results are printed for in all cases.

You need to either split up your `printf` calls so that `byte_to_binary` is only called once each time, or copy off the result into temporaries and print those.  You're doing the latter in the second `printf` call, so just use that and remove the third.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to the same `static` buffer from every call to `byte_to_binary`, so by the time the `printf` reads them they have (or rather, it has) only the last result.

Comment: Note that "the last result" here means whichever result happens to be the last; the order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified by the C standard. However, they will all be evaluated before passing to `printf` (and _not_, for example, only when used by `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    ...
    return b;
}
```

This function is not reentrant and returns a pointer to local value. So using it like : `byte_to_binary(ch), byte_to_binary(ch & a)` will yield the same result twice, as the pointer value is the same(!).

But you can pass allocated space to your function:

```
const char *byte_to_binary(int x, char b[9]) { 
   ...
   return b; 
}
```

And call using constant literal:

```
byte_to_binary(ch, (char[9]){0}), byte_to_binary(ch & a, (char[9]){0}),
```

This will allocate needed 9 chars on each function call. You can make that a macro:

```
const char *byte_to_binary_in(int x, char b[9]) { 
   ...
   return b; 
}
#define byte_to_binary(x)  byte_to_binary_in(x, (char[9]){0})
```

And have stay with the same interface, while your function stays reentrant.

Keep in mind however, that compound literals stop existing when exiting from a block, ie. after `}`.

P.S. Have fun and see my small function `printbinary` and macro `PRINTBINARY_t(...)`, [header](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/blob/master/src/lib/printex.h#L16) and [src](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/blob/master/src/lib/printex.c#L18). However there are maaany solution over the net for printing binary numbers.

Comment: Thank you all very much, that makes tons of sense.

Comment: A stylistic nitpick: I would stay away from defining the length of an array argument of a function since it obfuscates the fact that it becomes a pointer argument regardless, and gives the false impression that, for example, `sizeof` could be used on it to determine the array size.

Comment: @Arkku I maybe really though that too for some time and was against the new 15 principle in the new [C2x chapter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2086.htm). Once you start using it, doing `array_do_smth(size_t len, arrtype_t arr[static len]);` (ok, I don't use static keyword there that much) it gets really verbose to see how big the size of an array is. But true, it maybe is sometimes misleading for the `sizeof` and the type of the address-of operator. Anyway, I am against such a stylistic nitpick, but don't really care if someone uses pointers.

Comment: Both your example in the comment and the one in the principle 15 have the VLA syntax. I personally find that more acceptable since `len` is given as a separate argument, which also removes the temptation to use `sizeof` to determine it. However, the magic constant `9` I would avoid, especially if it would then have to be duplicated inside the function (e.g., `i < 9`, although that doesn't appear in this particular case). Something like `b[CHAR_BIT + 1]` would be less objectionable.